# XAMPP Localhost ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I am using XAMPP on MAC. It has been working for a few months. I was using Port 80 and Port 89 for a Virtual Host.

I haven't done anything recently (maybe the problem comes from the fact that I am connected to a public Wi-Fi... that is the only difference), but it has stopped working.
When I go to localhost/, my browser shows : ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Nothing looks wrong on the Application Log...

Do you have any idea which could help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does `localhost` still map to `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: Where can i see it ?

Comment: You can ping `localhost` in Terminal, or you can view it in `/etc/hosts`. Make sure the Apache is listening to port 80.

Comment: Thank you, I found that the localhost line disappeared from /etc/hosts, I added this line : 127.0.0.1 localhost and now it works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, `localhost` is not mapped to `127.0.0.1`. After added the entry `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/etc/hosts`, the XAMPP works fine.